# Summary statistics using vlookup or nested IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-loops, vlookup, vba

So I have an output table that I need to summarize into another table. The output table creates a row for each hour of every day, for 28 days. so there is 672 rows for each KPI I measure. I need to summarize these in a table, based on the amount of data I have. For example, sometimes I might only have data for 7 days, but my excel file will just fill in zeros for the rest of the days. I need to create a nested IF and/or vlookup function that will read the amount of data I have(either by figuring it out itself or me putting in my own value and it reading) and then summarize it by hour. I need to categorize the data hourly, so the output table will look like this.

```
hour   min   max   avg
1      7     10   8
2      8     12   9
3      6     9    7
...
24     5    12    8
```

and my current input table looks like this

```
hour  value
1       7
2       8
3       11
...
672     13
```

although sometimes it could not go the full way to 672, and I want it to ignore all zero values if so.

Answer (score 1):

for min and max it doesn't matter.  for average do sumif / countif

Comment: Gave you an up vote. It can still matter for min or max though depending on the range of the values. I think you got the right idea to solve this problem though.